# Renaming "messy" dataframe level names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a "messy" dataframe with factor level names all over the place

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A.", "zB,", "Cs", "At", "Dp", "Df")),
                   V2=factor(c("Af", "A_", "A_", ".A", "D.", "rB")))
```

I want to rename my levels so that I only have A, B, C, and D levels.

I can do it for each individual level using:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) { revalue(x, c("A."="A")) }))
```

But that's time-consuming for a large dataframe.

Is there a way to automate this, so that every level that contains the letter "A" is renamed to A (whether it's called A. or Af) etc.?

Comment: Do you just want to relabel with the first character? Or is there a different pattern?

Comment: @camille: A different pattern. What I basically want is to rename any level with "A" in it to A etc. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Gregor: _E_ was a typo. I've removed it.

Comment: @KaC Now it doesn't work because they are different lengths though

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly general solution.

```
#' @description Renames factor levels containing a pattern 
#' @details  If an input element matches more than one pattern, the first will be used.
#' @param f Factor or character vector to modify
#' 
#' @param pattern Pattern to match (regex optional)
#' @param label Label to assign for each pattern. Defaults to the pattern
#' @param ... Extra arguments passed to `grep`
#' @return Vector of the same type as `f`, with any elements matching a `pattern`
#' replaced by the corresponding `label`.
#' 
#' @author Gregor Thomas
contain_relabel = function(f, pattern, label= pattern, ...) {
    if (length(pattern) != length(label)) stop("pattern and label must have same")
    is_input_factor = is.factor(f)
    f = as.character(f)
        for (i in seq_along(pattern)) {
        f[grep(pattern[i], f, ...)] = label[i]
    }
    if (is_input_factor) return(factor(f))
    return(f)
}

V1 = factor(c("A.", "zB,", "Cs", "At", "Dp", "Df"))
contain_relabel(V1, "A")
# [1] A   zB, Cs  A   Dp  Df 
# Levels: A Cs Df Dp zB,

contain_relabel(V1, LETTERS[1:4])
# [1] A B C A D D
# Levels: A B C D
```

---

Just like any other function that takes and returns a vector, you can use `lapply` on your data frame to apply it to all columns:

```
DF[] = lapply(DF, contain_relabel, pattern = LETTERS[1:4])
DF
#   V1 V2
# 1  A  A
# 2  B  A
# 3  C  A
# 4  A  A
# 5  D  D
# 6  D  B
```

You can apply it to only factor columns with

```
fc = sapply(DF, is.factor)
DF[fc] = lapply(DF[fc], ...<same as above>...)
```

---

The generality is that it will default to renaming to the pattern match as above, but you can also be more flexible. For example, if you wanted anything containing "A" to be renamed to "Alpha", you could do `contain_relabel(x, "A", "Alpha")`. You can also use `...` to pass arguments through to `grep` in case you want to make it case insensitive, use a fixed pattern instead of regex, etc.

Comment: This works very well for the example, but since the solution only works for one factor at a time, it remains very time-consuming for a range dataframe.

Comment: I didn't bother showing you how to `lapply` it since you had `lapply` in your question. `DF[] = lapply(DF, contain_relabel, pattern = LETTERS[1:4])`.

Answer (score 4):

For this example, you can do it quickly with `stringr::str_extract`  and apply across each column with `mutate_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% mutate_all(stringr::str_extract, "[A-D]")
  V1 V2
1  A  A
2  B  A
3  C  A
4  A  A
5  D  D
6  D  B
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution for this example, but I was hoping for something more general-purpose. E.g. what if some of the level names are numbers or some more complex renaming is necessary, e.g. "uniquestringoftext1" --> "1". (I supposed it's kind of a separate question, but really the same problem.)

Comment: @KaC It depends if you can construct a regex to identify what you want to pick out that works for all of the data. If so you can put it in this solution, otherwise I can't see any other way than having to deal with cases individually, using `car::recode` for example

Comment: It seems that, as long as there is any kind of pattern that can be discerned, whether it's letters or numeric, one can use `as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) regmatches(x, regexpr("[1-2]", x))))` suggested by @camille. Still, it's a shame there doesn't seem to be a way to simply specify: here's a name/string of text anywhere in the dataframe, rename it to "x"

Answer (score 3):

Since what you need is to extract the capital letter, A, B, C, or D, from each element, it's well suited to regex to extract matches for `"[A-D]"`.

Here are 3 ways, depending on preference. The first uses `lapply` to apply `regmatches` and `regexpr` to each column. The second uses `lapply` to apply `str_extract` from `stringr`, which is a wrapper around `stri_extract` from `stringi`. The third skips the `lapply` and instead uses `mutate_all` from `dplyr` to apply a function across all columns (or `mutate_at` if you need this for a subset of columns), and `str_extract` again.

```r
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A.", "zB,", "Cs", "At", "Dp", "Df")),
                                 V2=factor(c("Af", "A_", "A_", ".A", "D.", "rB")))

as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) regmatches(x, regexpr("[A-D]", x))))
#>   V1 V2
#> 1  A  A
#> 2  B  A
#> 3  C  A
#> 4  A  A
#> 5  D  D
#> 6  D  B

as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) stringr::str_extract(x, "[A-D]")))
#>   V1 V2
#> 1  A  A
#> 2  B  A
#> 3  C  A
#> 4  A  A
#> 5  D  D
#> 6  D  B

library(tidyverse)
DF %>% mutate_all(str_extract, "[A-D]")
#>   V1 V2
#> 1  A  A
#> 2  B  A
#> 3  C  A
#> 4  A  A
#> 5  D  D
#> 6  D  B
```

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Hmm, all of these options work very well for the example, but I was hoping for a more general-purpose solution. It's my fault for simplifying the example too much. What if there isn't such a clear pattern to the levels? E.g. one level could be "A." that needs to be renamed to "A", but another is ""uniquestringoftext1" that needs to become simply "1".

Comment: Okay, that's why I initially asked for the pattern you need to match. You should figure out exactly what the pattern is and add that to your question. Otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: It would be good to have a solution that doesn't require a clear pattern, but--as I wrote above--I guess the `as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) regmatches(x, regexpr("[A-B]", x))))` option is most versatile if there is some kind of a pattern.

Comment: I just don't know how we would extract or relabel text based on a pattern that we don't have. If you need to recode manually, there's `forcats::fct_recode`. But if the problem is you *don't* want to do it manually, you need a pattern of some sort and you need to let us know what that pattern is exactly

Comment: If we think of a pattern broadly, my idea was to find, for example, any level in the dataframe with the word "Random" (e.g. "Very long name blabla Random more blabla") in its name, and then rename that level to "Random". That doesn't seem to be possible--and `fct_recode` obviously can't do this, both because it only works on a single factor at a time and requires precise name.

Comment: @KaC I'm not sure what you don't think that's possible. *any level in the dataframe with the word "Random"*, then `"Random"` is your pattern. It will work with any of the answers here - this one, mine or James's. My answer will let you do the "uniquestringoftext1" --> "1" you mention in another comment as well (see my "A" --> "Alpha" example).

Comment: And in fact they do. Thank you,  @Gregor.